# Gerrit - same patchset multiple verified labels

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, label

I am working on a project that has gerrit-jenkins trigger set up. I uploaded a patchset and the jenkins job was not completely correct thus the job failed and posted a -1 Verified label on the gerrit patchset.

Thereafter, I submitted a +1 verified label manually. My question is, if the same patchset has multiple verified labels (-1 and +1), does it allow to submit the change if the last label is +1 (even if its manually and not via jenkins).

I cannot test this change on the project I'm working on because of permission issues and the official documentation doesn't say anything about precedence of multiple verified labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone has changed the default [Verified label](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_Verified) configuration, the -1 vote will block the submit even if the +1 vote exists.

```
[label "Verified"]
      function = MaxWithBlock
      value = -1 Fails
      value =  0 No score
      value = +1 Verified
```

The function = MaxWithBlock means:

The lowest possible negative value, if present, blocks a submit, while the highest possible positive value is required to enable submit. There must be at least one positive value, or else submit will never be enabled. To permit blocking submits, ensure a negative value is defined.

More info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_function).

Comment: "There must be at least one positive value, or else submit will never be enabled". Does this mean that even if there is an older -1 on the same patchset, if later a +1 is posted on same patchset, submit will be allowed?

Comment: No, it will NOT be allowed because: "the lowest possible negative value, if present, blocks a submit".